# How to iterate over itertools::chunks

Tags: rust

I'm a new rustacean, so my code's quality is questionable.
While trying to get the ropes of rust, I've come across the following problem.

I have a vector of bits (`bool`s), and I want to convert then into a vector of bytes (`u8`)

My first implementation looked like that

```
let mut res: Vec<u8> = vec![];
let mut curr = 0;
for (idx, &bit) in bits.iter().enumerate() {
    let x = (idx % 8) as u8;
    if idx % 8 != 0 || idx == 0 {
        curr = set_bit_at(curr, (7 - (idx % 8)) as u32, bit).unwrap();
    } else {
        res.push(curr);
        curr = 0
    }
}
res.push(curr);
```

It worked, but It felt pretty ugly, so I've tried to implement it using the crate itertools.

```
let res = bits.iter()
    .chunks(8)
    .map(|split_byte: Vec<u8>| {
        split_byte.fold(0, |res, &bit| (res << 1) | (bit as u8))
    })
    .collect();
```

It sure looks nicer, but sadly - it didn't work.

Even though it seems as if `chunks`'s return type [seems](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.4.8/itertools/struct.Chunks.html) to be an iterator, this line produced the following error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `map` found for type `bits::itertools::IntoChunks<std::slice::Iter<'_, bool>>` in the current scope
```

Could anyone tell what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you have misread the doc here. The right part for you is [here](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks). Where you'll see that (emphasis mine):

> Return an **iterable** that can chunk the iterator.
>
> IntoChunks is based on GroupBy: **it is iterable (implements**
>   **IntoIterator, not Iterator)**, and it only buffers if several chunk
>   iterators are alive at the same time.

Hence, you need to use `into_iter` before your `map`.